# Can I obtain information about the windows explorer tree (left pane)?

Tags: winapi, treeview, windows-explorer

Is it possible to obtain information about the Windows Explorer tree (what nodes are currently expanded, when a node is expanded etc.)?

[image]

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: For the available tree view control messages, see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486106(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks.

Comment: I edited your question to make it a bit more generic, see if you agree. I removed the screenshot because it's too big (you need to scroll to get to comments/answers), and kind of redundant - people know what a tree view control, they don't need a screenshot. Also is the language C++? It matters, and you should tag it.

Comment: See this experts exchange link - http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_20443710.html

Comment: I'm actually specifically interested in the windows explorer tree. I'm not sure if it matters. Maybe the explorer process broadcasts the changes to the tree to other processes. Maybe there are some WinAPI functions that help me achieve what I want. I don't know if it's a good idea to make it more generic.

Comment: It does not matter. It's a good idea to make it as generic as possible. That way people searching for the generic question will land here. Did you roll back my edits?

Comment: Note that most tree messages won't work across the process boundary. What information are you trying to get from the tree? Using injection techniques you could query things like item label and open/close state but getting the full path (rather than the label) would be much harder.

Comment: What the problem you want to solve? Do you understand that tree may be hidden? Do you understand that in next version of Windows tree may have absolutely other structure or tree may be created with using of other controls and your code will be broken. Why you want to use "hacks" like reading internal states of tree nodes?

Comment: @DenisAnisimov I am aware of all of these. I don't want to use "hacks". I want to know if there's a way to achieve these (current tree state, node state modification) via WinAPI functions.

Comment: Where your code is placed? Inside BHO? Inside shell extension? External program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Vista there is official way to communicate with tree in Explorer window. This way uses INameSpaceTreeControl interface.

If you want to get INameSpaceTreeControl from external app you must:

1) Get IDispatch of shell window:

```
var
  ShellWindows: IShellWindows;
  i: Integer;
  Dispatch: IDispatch;
  SL: TStrings;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_ShellWindows, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IShellWindows, ShellWindows));
  try
    for i := ShellWindows.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      begin
        Dispatch := ShellWindows.Item(i);
        try
          SL := CreateNodeList(Dispatch);
          try
            Memo1.Lines.Assign(SL);
          finally
            SL.Free;
          end;
          Exit;
        finally
          Dispatch := nil;
        end;
      end;
  finally
    ShellWindows := nil;
  end;
end;
```

2) Query IServiceProvider from IDispatch.

3) Query INameSpaceTreeControl from IServiceProvider.

4) After this you can enum elements of tree. I used the following algorithm:

```
function GetItemName(AShellItem: IShellItem): UnicodeString;
var
  Name: PWideChar;
begin
  OleCheck(AShellItem.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, Name));
  try
    Result := Name;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(Name);
  end;
end;

function GetLevelSpaces(ALevel: Integer): UnicodeString;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to ALevel - 1 do
    Result := Result + '    ';
end;

function CalcLavel(AShellItem: IShellItem): Integer;
var Parent: IShellItem;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Succeeded(AShellItem.GetParent(Parent)) then
    try
      Inc(Result);
      Result := Result + CalcLavel(Parent);
    finally
      Parent := nil;
    end;
end;

function GetExpanded(ATree: INameSpaceTreeControl; AItem: IShellItem): WideChar;
var
  State: DWORD;
begin
  OleCheck(ATree.GetItemState(AItem, NSTCIS_EXPANDED, State));
  if State and NSTCIS_EXPANDED <> 0 then Result := '+'
                                    else Result := '-';
end;

function CreateNodeList(ADispatch: IDispatch): TStrings;
var
  ServiceProvider: IServiceProvider;
  Tree: INameSpaceTreeControl;
  L: Integer;
  ShellItem, ShellItem2: IShellItem;
begin
  OleCheck(ADispatch.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider));
  try
    OleCheck(ServiceProvider.QueryService(SID_SNavigationPane, INameSpaceTreeControl, Tree));
    try
      Result := TStringList.Create;
      try
        if Succeeded(Tree.GetNextItem(nil, NSTCGNI_CHILD, ShellItem)) then
          repeat
            try
              L := CalcLavel(ShellItem);
              Result.Add(GetLevelSpaces(L - 1) + GetExpanded(Tree, ShellItem) + ' ' + GetItemName(ShellItem));
            finally
              ShellItem2 := ShellItem;
              ShellItem := nil;
            end;
          until Failed(Tree.GetNextItem(ShellItem2, NSTCGNI_NEXTVISIBLE, ShellItem));
      finally
        ShellItem2 := nil;
      end;
    finally
      Tree := nil;
    end;
  finally
    ServiceProvider := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Result:

[image: Explorer tree]

If you want to subscribe to tree actions use INameSpaceTreeControl.TreeAdvise.

Comment: For managed code solution do you have a Guid for SID_SNavigationPane ? @Denis Anisimov